# Memory Leak in method to remove line from list and delete row from sheet

Tags: excel, vba, memory-leaks, listbox

I am writing an application to manage parking stalls and I have run into a memory leak. I have spent some time fooling around with it and this is the first leak I have had where the cause was not apparent. The strangest part is that there is an identical method that refers to the apartment list which does not cause the memory leak. My memory usage jumps from 100k to 1000k at the xCell.EntireRow.Delete line and I get an out of memory error when it tries to remove the line from my ListBox.

A button calls removeStall. Here is my code:

```
Public Sub removeStall()
    Dim stall As String
    Dim lineNum As Long
    Dim answer As Integer

    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to remove this stall?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Remove Stall")
    If answer = vbYes Then

        lineNum = Sheet1.StallsList.ListIndex
        If lineNum > -1 Then

            stall = Sheet1.StallsList.List(lineNum)
            dropStall stall

        End If

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dropStall(stall As String)

    Dim stalls As Worksheet
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim lineNum As Long
    Dim lastLine As Long

    lineNum = Sheet1.BuildingListBox.ListIndex
    Set stalls = Worksheets(Sheet1.BuildingListBox.List(lineNum) & "stalls")
    lastLine = stalls.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each xCell In stalls.Range("B2:B" & lastLine)
        If xCell.value = stall Then

            xCell.EntireRow.Delete
            Sheet1.StallsList.RemoveItem (Sheet1.StallsList.ListIndex)
            Exit For

        End If

    Next xCell

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Edit:

Per the below comment I have checked to see if any of my change or lostfocus events are triggering just before the memory leak, and they are not.

Comment: How many formulas reference those cells?  Do you have any event subs in your workbook?

Comment: Quite a few. When this command is run, they were just brought over from another workbook using similar methods. I have gone through those methods and set all the objects that won't be unset by end sub (and I understand those to be the ones you have to use 'set' on) to nothing.

Comment: did you try just changing the order of these 2 lines         `xCell.EntireRow.Delete
            Sheet1.StallsList.RemoveItem`

Comment: Try setting calculation to manual before the loop and then back to automatic.  The more formulas that reference a range create a geometric increase in memory requirements and processor time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear before. There are no formulas, only workbook change events. I just tried reversing the order but got the same issue...